Ghost MDADM RAID Array appearing at boot
I recently ported my Ubuntu server into a VM using Proxmox and one thing that has been bothering me is that whenever I boot the system it shows me md127 in my RAID arrays in the Webmin console. I keep deleting it and it never shows up in the /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf file. I even purged mdadm and reinstalled it which should have deleted any stray config files.
Webmin showing 3 RAID devices
And the config file only shows this:
# This configuration was auto-generated on Sun, 03 Nov 2024 11:36:57 -0500 by mkconf
ARRAY /dev/md0 uuid=3b9ce0fa:481ca823:8ac4e730:9785d762
ARRAY /dev/md1 uuid=ef92edbe:51d8d22c:995fa3f2:7341ce36

Does anyone know where this strange third RAID array is coming from?
Thanks!

How are you able to do RAID 5 on two disks? I wonder if that third "device" is showing up because you need at least three disks for RAID 5 and maybe your RAID controller is trying make something up to compensate.

@Colin Each of the RAID 5 arrays have 5 disks, you can see them in the screenshot under Member Disk Devices. I also don't have a hardware RAID controller, this is all software RAID
